# How to take backup of system databases?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know to how to take backup of system databases? and is there any difference between taking backup of user databases and system database? and how to restore? I need T-SQL command?

Answer (score 7):

The commands are the same, that's true, but system DBs do need special consideration both for backup and for restore. The topic is discussed at length in the [Considerations for Backing Up and Restoring System Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190.aspx) chapter in BOL. This has also 4 sub-chapters about backing up and restoring `master`on one hand, and `model` and `msdb` on the other hand. Read the documentation first, then come back if you still have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Backing up a system database is basically the same than backing up a non-system database, as marc_s already pointed out in his comment.

One difference is that the system databases are always in [Simple Recovery Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx), so it's not possible to do transaction log backups.

Comment: [This is patently untrue.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190190(v=sql.90).aspx)